# Angular / JavaScript adding unwanted &nbsp; tag through API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, xmlhttprequest

New to Angular trying to navigate through this, so please bear with me.

We have an API setup, that's pulling in data through JavaScript/Angular for our products. Trying to pull in a banner and place it on our site.

It works great for the English side, but for the French side it won't pull in. It looks like a   tag is being inserted between the phrases, which is causing it not to be pulled in.

**English side** (working - no nbsp tag being inserted):

[image]

**French side** (not working - nbsp tag is being inserted).

[image]

**Product.html**

```
<!--Promotion Banner-->
  <div
    id="promoBannerModel"
    data-model="{{vm.product.Name}}"
    ng-controller="Product"
  >
    <div
      ng-include="'/app/battlefield-fr/product/promo-banner.html'"
      ng-show="vm.promoBanner.show"
    ></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `vm.promoBanner.show` has the correct value?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it does! It works perfectly on the English side for same product, doesn't work on the French side though. On the French side, it adds a nbsp; tag inbetween the phrase. Does this for all French products.

Comment: I still think you need to check that value because in the screenshot a class of `ng-hide` is applied on child div of `#promoBannerModel` which can only happen if `vm.promoBanner.show` is `false`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava turns out it actually works for most French products, only 8 of them don't show. So for all but 8 products, for some reason it's applying the ng-hide.